# How can I pass props down to a child component that is wrapped in a container using reselect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I am trying to pass down props from a parent component to a child component that is wrapped in a container. I would like to use a selector to use the string that is passed down as props so that it can select the substate of parent data.

Right now data is structured as following:

```
Industry: {
 Data: {
  coolants: [array],
  machines: [array],
  tools: [array]
 }
}
```

Using selectors I am able to select for all industry data however I am trying to use selectors to select for 'coolants' only

In my parent component, I am passing down the props to select for 'coolants': 
`<ChartContainer category='coolants' />`

ChartContainer.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    data: makeSelectData(),
})

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, null)
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'industry', reducer })

export default compose (
    withReducer,
    withConnect
)(ChartComponent);
```

selectors.js

```
const selectDomain = () => state => state.get('industry')

const makeSelectData = () => createSelector(
  selectDomain(),
  substate => substate.toJS()
)

export {
  makeSelectData
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things:

1. use your component props' category value in your selector ([mapStateToProps docs: ownProps](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments));
2. using this props get nested value in your immutable data structure ([ImmutableJS docs: getIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/getIn));

Possible change is:

```
const selectDomain = () => (state, props) => state.getIn(['industry', props.category])
```